# Xamarin Executor that takes Callable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, callable, executor

***Part I***

Hi, I am trying to alter the following piece of code to take Callable instead of 
Runnable, because I want the functions that are fed to the Executor to return
data.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using Java.Lang;

namespace ServiceExecutor {
    [Activity(Label = "SomeActivity")]
    public class SomeActivity : Activity {
        TextView tv1;

        Runnable r;            
        static IExecutorService exe = Executors.NewSingleThreadExecutor();        

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            tv1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                r = new Runnable(() => function(i));
                exe.Submit(r);
            }
        }

        public void function(int i) {
            RunOnUiThread(() => tv1.Text += "function " + i.ToString() + "\r\n");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }    
    }
}
```

I have found examples in Java but when I'm trying to replicate the code in C#
the main class Callable is missing and there is only ICallable which I can't 
instantiate. Unfortunately the Xamarin documentation also gives Java examples!

I would appreciate if anyone could help!

***Part II***

The complete design idea is a Service the has this embedded Executor to run
tasks sequentially. The sequential execution is cruicial because the service
will have continuous socket connection with the bluetooth interface and only
one bluetooth request (task) can be handled at a time. Initially I wanted to use 
IntentService but I want the service to be alive throughout the life of the
application, otherwise for each bluetooth request the socket will have to
reconnect.

Any advice for the design approach will also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# example of `ICallable` and `IFuture` that just returns the same string that you supplied...

#### Implement an `ICallable`-based class:

Within the `Call()` method is where you implement your calculations and return the result, the `ExecutorService` is responsible for calling this method and storing the result.

```
public class BoomerangeCallable<T> : Java.Lang.Object, ICallable
{
    T value;
    public BoomerangeCallable(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Java.Lang.Object Call()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

#### Usage Example:

```
var futures = new Stack<IFuture>();
var executor = Executors.NewSingleThreadExecutor();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var br = new BoomerangeCallable<string>("StackOverflow");
    futures.Push(executor.Submit(br));
}
while (futures.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(futures.Pop().Get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, do you think I should get rid of Java and stay with a .NET implementation like using a thread pool?

Comment: @NikosD Personally I try to avoid Java peer objects as much as I can and stay in the C# VM.... That said, I wish C# had something in the framework, as simple to use as the `ExecutorService` ;-)  The way I would do it is to add a `Action`s to a `BlockingCollection` and consume/invoke those `BlockingCollection` Actions within a standalone thread...